# Accessing Ninject Kernel.Get() from HttpHandler with existing custom base

Tags: webforms, ninject, httphandler

I have an ASP.Net webforms app, that uses Ninject 2.2.0.0

I have a HTTPHandler that inherits from the Microsoft.Web.ImageHandler class.

Within it i need to access an instance of a service class that i created.

because i cannot inherit from Ninject.Web.HttpHandlerBase i thought i would just expose the Kernel as a property on the Global.asax class...

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new DefaultModule());

        var sms = kernel.Get<SiteMapService>();
        SiteMapSvc = sms;
        Kernel = kernel;
        return kernel;

    }

    public IKernel Kernel
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

and use the kernel.Get method to obtain the service..

```
var global = (Global) HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;

var service = global.Kernel.Get<PhotoService>();
```

This fails with the following...

```
   [ArgumentNullException: Cannot be null
Parameter name: root]
   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, Func`2 constraint, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean isOptional, Boolean isUnique) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:258
   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:151
   Thumb.GenerateImage(NameValueCollection parameters) in \Thumb.ashx.cs:40
```

**UPDATE:**
I managed to fix this by modifying the Global.Kernel property to this, but now im getting into [anti pattern territory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)...

```
public IKernel Kernel
    {
        get { return this.CreateKernel(); }
    }
```

Will now read up and see what this means..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is using the [Service-Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).  It will work, but you lose the flexibility of IoC and add a dependency everywhere that is difficult to test.

This simple answer is that you can add "KernelContainer.Inject(this)" to your HttpHandler.  Or you can create a custom module (or modify the existing Ninject.Web one) to do injection before handler execution.

Comment: it did seem like a hack, thats for sure.  Thanks for the pointer to KernelContainer.  Shall spend some time on this.

Comment: Loss of the Compile time ability to checking of my application missing major pieces that it needs to run seems a very heavy price to pay indeed to decrease coupling.