# Ninject Runtime Exception occuring frequently - System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: ninject

I am using Ninject 2.2.1.0 with Ninject.Web 2.2.0.0 in a webforms application.

I am getting daily error reports of the following...

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration
> ```
>
> operation may not execute.
>          at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource)
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>          at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1
>   series, Action`1 action) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:line
>   22
>          at Ninject.OnePerRequestModule.DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest()
>   in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\OnePerRequestModule.cs:line
>   63
>          at Ninject.OnePerRequestModule.b__0(Object
>   o, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\OnePerRequestModule.cs:line
>   36
>          at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>          at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Seems to be occuring at peak times.  Is there a stable release with this patched yet?

Comment: Are you creating new instances of StandardKernel frequently?

Comment: Effectively - yes.  I need to access my service objects in a HttpHandler and there is no way i can inherit from the Ninject HttpHandler as it inherits from a custom HttpHandler already.  I had been advised to access the kernel via KernelContainer but this appears to be an internal class.  What would you advise?

Comment: this is the original predicament i was in that i mention in my comment above - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523130/accessing-ninject-kernel-get-from-httphandler-with-existing-custom-base

Comment: Inherit from Ninject HttpHandler and decorate the one you want to derive from isn't an option?

Comment: The handler utility serves images and is in Microsoft.Web.GeneratedImage.dll so my handler must inherit from the base handler (ImageHandler) in order to return the images.  I cannot see how i can do this without simulating multiple inheritance, which itself seems impossible given the functionality that the imageHandler provides.  Is there any way i can access 'the' kernel instance in a 'service locator type fashion' and get an instance of the service i require directly?

Comment: I ended up finding the source code for the GeneratedImage library on codeplex and compiled my own version that inherits from the Ninject HttpHandlerBase

Comment: What I would do is to derive from Ninject, inject one instance of ImageHandler and forward everything you would normally pass to base to this instance.

Comment: aha, i see what you mean now.  Never considered that approach, although things are working fine now.  Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation of kernel instances is not thread safe at the moment. This will probably be changed with 2.4