# Ninject throwing "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" error

Tags: collections, ninject, enumeration, was

I am using the following 2 Ninject assemblies in my web project.

```
Ninject.dll – Version 2.2.0.0
Ninject.Web.dll – Version 2.2.0.4
```

I have noticed that when I perform load testing on the server I am getting exceptions in my which are pointing to the Ninject

> Message: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not
>   execute.  Stack Trace:     at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource)     at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()     at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()     at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()     at
>   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1
>   series, Action`1 action) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:line
>   22     at
>   Ninject.OnePerRequestModule.DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest()
>   in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\OnePerRequestModule.cs:line
>   63     at Ninject.OnePerRequestModule.b__0(Object o, EventArgs
>   e) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\OnePerRequestModule.cs:line
>   36     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I did find this link from Remo Gloor dated May 11 2011 which says there is a new 2.4 version which has mentioned that the problem will be fixed 2.4 version. I am not sure if this version is released/available yet as I not able to find it.
[Ninject Runtime Exception occuring frequently - System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028564/ninject-runtime-exception-occuring-frequently-system-invalidoperationexception)

Does anybody know the solution to this resolve this Ninject error or know where can I find the 2.4 version?

---

This is the way I have done the mapping using Version 2.2.0.0 of Ninject

```
Bind<IMyEntities>().To<MyEntities>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString);
```

Using 3.0 I changed it to use

```
Bind<IMyEntities>().ToConstructor(x => new MyEntities());
```

or

```
Bind<IMyEntities>().ToConstructor(x => new MyEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString));
```

or

```
Bind<IMyEntities>().ToConstructor(x => new MyEntities(new EntityConnection (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString)));
```

After trying all the above mentioned 3 different ways I am still getting the error. Every time the 3rd constructor is getting called somehow.
I am not sure what else to try. I have kind of invested a very good amount of time trying different things and still not coming to a conclusion/resolution. 
If I am not able to find/resolve this problem somehow I will have to remove all the Ninjet references all together and go for some other DI's.

Answer (score 0):

2.4 has become 3.0 because of some minor interface incompatibilities. See http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/3.0.0-rc3

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is Ninject 3.0.0-rc3 a pre release candiate. If so do you kow when will it be released?

Comment: It is, but as of now it will be 100% binary compatible with the upcomming release in a few days.

Comment: Ok, thanks. After I updated my web project to use the 3.0 version I got an error "The type or namespace name 'NinjectHttpApplication' could not be found". Can you please help me find the documentation for the version 3.0 and what has changed between 2.2.0.0 vs 3.0.

Comment: I was able to resolve the previous error but now I am getting this one: Ninject.Syntax.IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax does not contain a definition for 'InRequestScope' and no extension method 'InRequestScope' accepting a first argument of type  <''>

Comment: add using Ninject.Web.Common;

Comment: ok changed that, but now getting a new error saying [ArgumentException: The supplied connection is not valid because it contains insufficient mapping or metadata information.

Comment: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/30/new-features-and-changes-of-ninject-3-0/ => Entity Framework

Comment: i do not think that is the problem. My web site was working fine with Ninect 2.2.0.0 version. This happens only after updating my Ninject version to 3.0 pre release candidate.

Comment: Have you even read the blog post? It is about (breaking)changes of Ninject. Quite sure this is your problem.

Comment: Yes I tried this with my entiried which is mentioned on the blog post this.Bind<MyEntities>().ToConstructor(x => new MyEntities()); Even after that I kept getting the error  [ArgumentException: The supplied connection is not valid because it contains insufficient mapping or metadata information. For some reason it default constructor does not get hit, instead the one with EntityConnection is getting called everytime and the connection parameter to is not getting initialized correctly which then throws the error.

Comment: This means another binding is used to create your entities. change this binding to force the parameterless constructor with the given approach.

Comment: @user1202347 Can you tell us how you fixed the "The type or namespace name 'OnePerRequestModule' could not be found" error?